# PDO Search Engine Trouble

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make an advanced search engine, one in which you can search by first name, last name, zip, city, state, phone, cell phone and email.

I have managed to get it to search by first name, but you have to type the first name correctly as with anything else, I took out everything else but the first name search to find my problem yet, I have yet to find it, Here is a MySQL version of my search code that I am trying to convert to PDO.

MySQL:

```
<?php
    //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 

    if ($searching =="yes")  {
        echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>";
        //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 

        if ($find == "")
        if ($f == "")
        if ($info == "")
        if ($zip == "")
        if ($state == "")
        if ($email == "")

        {
            echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term";
            exit;
        }

        // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
        mysql_connect("xxx", "xxxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
        // We preform a bit of filtering 

        //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($find)      . "%' AND lname 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($f)         . "%' AND info 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($info)      . "%' AND zip 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($zip)       . "%' AND state
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($state)     . "%' AND email 
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($city)  . "%' AND city
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($email)     . "%'");
?>


<?php

 //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
  { 
  echo "<hr><br>First Name:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $result['fname'];
 echo "<br>Last Name:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $result['lname']; 
 echo "<br>Home Phone:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $result['info']; 
 echo "<br>Cell Phone:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $result['cp']; 
 echo "<br>City:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $result['city']; 
 echo "<br>State:&nbsp;"; 
  echo $result['state']; 
 echo "<br>Zip:&nbsp;"; 
 echo $result['zip']; 
 echo "<br>Email:&nbsp;"; 
echo $result['email']; 
 echo "<br><hr>"; 


 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 
 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:
        </b> " .$find; 
  }
 ?>
```

Now here is my PDO version:

```
<?
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8';
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,'xxx','xxx', $opt);


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname= ?");



if ($stmt->execute(array($fname)));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {


        print $row['fname'] . "<br>";
        print $row['lname'] . "\t<br>";
        print $row['info'] . "\n<br>";
        print $row['cp'] . "\n<br>";
        print $row['state'] . "\n<br>";
        print $row['city'] . "\n<br>";
        print $row['zip'] . "\n<br>";
        print $row['email'] . "\n<br>";

  }



    ?>
```

Tips, advice, and comments are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Belongs to a [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: You stil need to use like so it have to be: `fname LIKE ?` Also you need to add the % charter to the variabele before you execute the query

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would build a sql-string and use parameters.
You would not include into your sql fields that the user left empty.

```
// **EDIT** check if there's any user-input...

if (!isset($_POST['fname']) && !isset($_POST['lname'])) { // add all your input-fields 

    echo "<p>please enter a search term!</p>";
    echo '<a href="search.php">try again</a>";
    exit();
}

    $sql = '';
    $bind = array();

if (strlen($_POST[‘firstname‘]) > 0) { // assuming your form-method is "post"
   $sql .= 'AND fname LIKE :fname ';
   $bind['fname'] = '%'.$_POST['firstname'].'%';
}

if (strlen($_POST['lastname']) > 0) 
    $sql .= 'AND lname LIKE :lname ';
    $bind['lname'] = '%'.$_POST['lastname'].'%';
}
// ...
// do this will all of your input-fields...

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ' . trim($sql, 'AND') . ' ORDER BY lname';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($bind));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// go ahead and display your results with foreach...
```

Comment: getting upvote back. wrong quotes around `‘firstname‘`, no `%`s for LIKE and too much `AND`s in the query. though approach if right in general

Comment: @YourCommonSense: edited the %-part right after having posted my answer. What about the wrong quotes and the ANDs? pls explain!

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY lname' at line 1' in /home/content/33/10329233/html/pdotest.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/33/10329233/html/pdotest.php(29): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/content/33/10329233/html/pdotest.php on line 29


On that :/

Comment: I'd hate to pester you with my problems Michi :/

Comment: e string(41) "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ORDER BY lname" is what it said at the top

Comment: @Jon relax, dude, no problem. see my edited answer in a few secs. There's no input into the textfield, the WHERE condition is empty and the sql invalid.

Comment: Hmmm  now it's just showing me  please enter a search term! and wont show a form nothing LOL! :) so sorry Michi

Comment: I have a form already hehe :) I'm just saying something is making to to where the form wont show, and I've looked and all coding is closed and neat  :/ DAMN!

Comment: Okay Michi, I am having trouble with it entirely to work, I keep getting an error about the Syntax of the SQL Query the error report says it's the syntax of ' ORDER BY lname'; :/

Comment: @Jon: look at the sql by `var_dump($sql)`, open a new question and post your code and the error-msg, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is you’re using `AND` instead of `OR` in your `WHERE` clause. Change it to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%string%'
OR `zip` LIKE '%string%'
// AND SO ON
```